# How the local variable inside a array of functions can be accessed outside of the block

Tags: javascript

I have snippet below, where `values` become as array of functions.  Each function contains a console.log(i); Where `i` was a local variable of the loop.  However when i execute (`values[1]()`) the values array the console.log is printing the i values. I'm trying to understand how this is possible

```
var values = [];

for ( let i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
{

  values.push(function() {
    console.log(i);
  })

}
console.log(values);  /* output :  Array [function() {
    console.log(i);
  }, function() {
    console.log(i);
  }]*/

values[0](); // output: 0

values[1](); // output: 1
```

Comment: This is called a closure. See the linked question above for an explanation.

Comment: It's possible because the function *closes over* the `i` variable, and because you used `let`, there's a different `i` variable for each loop iteration. (If you'd used `var`, there would be just one and all the `console.log` statements would output the value `2`.) FWIW, I go into some detail about this -- specifically in regard to `let` in a `for` loop like that -- in my new book in Chapter 2. ;-) See my profile for links.

Comment: I think this statement  _"The genius is that in JavaScript a function reference also has a secret reference to the closure it was created in"_   from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/111111/12025408)  clarifies the question i have